# Name for $\eta(\theta) \cdot T(x)$ in exponential family distributions

Tags: terminology, exponential-family, multinomial-logit

This is a terminology question. Distributions in the exponential family take the form
$$
f(x \mid \theta) = h(x)g(\theta) \exp(\eta(\theta) \cdot T(x))
\text{.}
$$
($\eta$ is the natural parameter, and $T$ gives the sufficient statistic(s) of $x$.)

If we treat this as a Boltzmann distribution $p(x) \propto \exp(- \beta \cdot \varepsilon_x)$ from statistical mechanics and set the constant $\beta$ to be 1 Joule$^{-1}$, we could comfortably call $\varepsilon_x$ the energy of the state. Continuing the statistical mechanics analogy, we might call $\eta \times T(x)$ the negative energy. But not all of us work in statistical mechanics. *Does $\eta \cdot T(x)$ have a common name in the statistics literature?*

Comment: I've only ever seen $\eta$ called the canonical/natural parameter and $T$ the canonical/natural statistic, I've never seen a specific name for $\eta \cdot T$. Although I don't feel confident enough to say definitely there is no name for this.

Comment: I do not think either that there is a well-recognised denomination in mathematical statistics for the scalar product. My best guess would be negative energy.